# Why declare function as variable?

Tags: javascript

While looking through an old codebase of ours, I came upon this little snippet:

```
var getElementByXpath = function (path) {
    return document.evaluate(path, document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue;
};
```

**Why did they declare a variable and assign an anonymous function to it, rather than simply create a named function?** How is that any different from the (much more normal and common) following?

```
function getElementByXpath(path) {
    return document.evaluate(path, document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue;
};
```

Comment: The main difference I know of is that if you declare the function as a variable, the function can only be called after the declaration. Simply using function name() is better because a: it takes less to type and b: it can be called from anywhere not just after.

Comment: @GwiddleWorker There's no "better" case here, the usage is just different.

Comment: @Teemu: Though in the many cases where both would work, function declarations [only have advantages](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html) over function expression assignments.